# New passport and entrance Schengen

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

I am from Brazil and travel a lot in Schengen countries. Under the rules of Schengen visa (3 months stay in a 6 months period). In my passport are the entrance and exit stamps, also to chec the days I stay in Schengen. 
I need a new passport and will get this in Brazil. So in this new passport are NOT the stamps. Does this mean I start new with the Schengen visa rule? I seems like. The new passport is empty. Or do I miss something? It would be great because I am almost on my 90 days stay in the period of 180 days.

Comment: @J.Constantine Actually that's not true generally... but is completely unrelated to whether you are allowed to do it or not. It's just that enforcement is more complicated.

Comment: @Relaxed Fair enough. Still, I'd say don't do it

Comment: @J.Constantine Indeed, I completely agree with that. And to be perfectly accurate, *some* entries are registered (typically in national systems that are not interconnected - yet!) so there is always a chance that you would get caught. And there will probably be a more comprehensive system at some point in the future.

Comment: @Relaxed thanks for the clarification! Learned something new today.

Answer (score 11):

No. The rules apply to you as an individual person, not to a specific passport. No matter how many passports you have, you, the unique human being, get 90 out of 180 days (otherwise a lot of people would be conveniently losing their passport regularly).

Comment: ... and dual nationals would be able to stay indefinitely by doing a visa run and switching passports every 90 days (+1).

Comment: Also they have finger-prints of visa holder, which, unfortunately does not change witg change of passport :)

Comment: @DavChana What visa holder? Brazilians are non-visa nationals